# How to submit form with file using ajax (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to submit form with file using AJAX. Earlier I used [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form), but now it not suitable. Because response from server is JSON with HTML format and this plugin do wrong JSON data.

I found [jQuery Ajax File Upload plugin](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/iframe-post-form.html), but not understand how to submit form to server. Help me fix problem with Form Plugin or send form with jQuery Ajax File Upload plugin.

This javascript code with Form Plugin:

```
$("#form").ajaxSubmit({
    success: 
        function(answer){
            var data = $.parseJSON(answer);

                $("#block").html(data.page);
                }
     }

});
```

Responce from server:

```
{"page": "<div id=\"some-div\">\r\n    <a href=\"/somelink\">somelink for examle</a>\r\n</div>"}
```

Data in success function before parse

```
{"page": "<div id="\&quot;some-div\&quot;">\r\n <a href="%5C%22/somelink%5C%22">somelink for examle</a>\r\n</div>"}
```

ParseJSON throws exception because \" in responce replace.

Comment: Can you show us some _code_ you've written that tries either plugin?  Both of these sites have demo code for their plugins.  What isn't working?  What do you mean by "does wrong JSON data"?

Comment: Yes, please. This javascript code with Form Plugin:
<pre><code>$("#form").ajaxSubmit({
 success:
     function(answer){
         var data = $.parseJSON(answer);
                $("#block").html(data.page);
                }
     }                                   
});</code></pre> 

Responce from server:{"page": "<div id=\"some-div\">\r\n    <a href=\"/somelink\">somelink for examle</a>\r\n</div>"}<br/>
Data in success function before parse:{"page": "<div id="\&quot;some-div\&quot;">\r\n <a href="%5C%22/somelink%5C%22">somelink for examle</a>\r\n</div>"}

Comment: you should add this code in your question, please edit the question. This is unreadable

Comment: It's because your escaping is not right in the markup. Each `"` for an html attribute or content should be escaped, such as `id=\"`. This would be *before* your webpage gets it, ie, on the server.

Comment: Yes, but server forming correct data, plugin before parsing replace simbols. If I use for test $.getJSON function, all data get correct.

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you tried omitting the `ParseJSON` part and just use the `answer`?

Comment: I can't, answer is already wrong. And responce from server consist from some variables.
I think that using another plugin may be easier. If someone has experience of usage the second plugin, please write a little example of code for send form to server. Or maybe you using another plugin?

Answer (score 0):

**use this code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitform").click(function(e)
{
var MyForm = JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeJSON());
console.log(MyForm);
 $.ajax(
 {
 url : "<your url>",
 type: "POST",
 data : MyForm,

 });
 e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action

});
});
</script>
```